# Bigquery stream insert and column value becomes null even though everything is valid

Tags: google-bigquery

I am doing streaming inserts into bigquery like this.

`insert_rows_json(table_bq, events, skip_invalid_rows = True, ignore_unknown_values = True)`

I log the data right before calling calling the method. However, the data sometimes gets randomly with user=null in bigquery.

And always is only **user** column who gets to null.
I can not replicate the issue, is happens completely random. But when it happens the whole batch (rows) that I try inserting get null for user.

Notes worth mentioning:

- our process is very high volume and pushes to thousands of tables
- some of the tables have not "user" column, but most of them have this
- for the ones that have "user" column, it was added after table creation.

  [
  {
  "url": "https://www.",
  "device": 1,
  "createdOn": 1700663528.0,
  "user": 9692442829539132,
  "type": 10007,
  "session": 969244282953913299
  },
  {
  "url": "h",
  "device": 1,
  "createdOn": 1700663528.0,
  "user": 2548791408809662,
  "type": 10007,
  "session": 254879140880966299
  },
  {
  "url": "https://",
  "device": 1,
  "createdOn": 1700663453.0,
  "user": 6493881270172166,
  "type": 10007,
  "session": 649388127017216699
  },
  {
  "url": "https://w",
  "device": 1,
  "createdOn": 1700663524.0,
  "user": 8504751515038746,
  "type": 10007,
  "session": 850475151503874699
  },
  {
  "url": "https://www.cl",
  "device": 2,
  "createdOn": 1700663461.0,
  "user": 8701121699677913,
  "type": 10007,
  "session": 870112169967791399
  },
  {
  "url": "https:",
  "device": 1,
  "createdOn": 1700663515.0,
  "user": 8504751515038746,
  "type": 10007,
  "session": 850475151503874699
  }]